# unable to open excel document using Python through openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

I'm new to Python, so sorry if this is annoyingly simple. I'm trying to simply open an excel document using this,

```html
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Users\ my file location here.xlsx') #with my real location
```

I didn't get any error, however i don't understand why file doesn't open ?

The location of the file is correct as I can open it using,

```html
file = "C:\Users\ my file location here.xlsx"
# os.startfile(file)
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to open the file *in Excel*. That is, you want to launch the Excel application, and have the file open in that application. OpenPyXL and xlrd are not designed to do this. In fact, they are specifically designed for working with the files when you can't or don't want to launch Excel. (For example, OpenPyXL and xlrd both work on Linux machines, which can't even run Excel.)

You probably want some kind of Excel automation, like you would get with VBA or VBScript or a .NET language, except you want to do it in Python. If so, the package you are looking for is **[xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/)**.

Comment: @Dan - The person asking the question doesn't say what they are expecting to happen with the first code snippet. There isn't enough there to demonstrate that they really understand the purpose and behavior of OpenPyXL. In the second snippet they use `os.startfile`. Yes, it's commented out, but it suggests *maybe* that when they say "open" they mean they want the file to be opened in Excel. If that isn't what they want, and they really are trying to use OpenPyXL the way it's meant to be used, then the question doesn't provide enough information for us to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try this first.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Users\ my file location here.xlsx')
type(wb)
```

2) else put your .py file in the same directory where .xlsx file is present and change code in .py as shown below.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('urfilename.xlsx')
type(wb)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's still not working, no error message, but it doesn't open the file.

Comment: @darrenvba could you please say what happens **exactly**? How do you know the file isn't open?

Comment: Nothing happens with that part of the code. If I change it to,

print ("hello")

import openpyxl
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('C:\Users\weirdh\Documents\python_trail_document.xlsx')
type(wb)

print ("hello again")

The print works fine, but seem to ignores the section were I try to open the excel file.

Comment: Not sure if you already got a notification for my answer, apologies if so. Do you think it could be an issue with how I installed the modules? Initially I couldn't install them my network as there was a firewall issue so I changed network to install them. They seemed to install fine but now i'm not so sure...

Answer (score 0):

you incorrectly invoke the load_workbook function

`wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Users\ my file location here.xlsx') #with my real location`

you should use just load_workbook

`wb = load_workbook('C:\Users\ my file location here.xlsx') #with my real location`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's still not working, no error message, but it doesn't open the file.

Comment: @yemu he did import the module with `import openpyxl`, so I  `openpyxl.load_workbook` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using `/` instead of `\` as folder delimiter.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/my file location here.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

   wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
```

os :- Window11

python:- 3.11.0

openpyxl:- 3.1.2

working